# MySQL select everything to left of last space in string with variable spaces

Tags: mysql

I have some data sent to us in columns that contains full names in one column.  The problem is that some names are split really strangely like thus:

```
John A Smith
Mary X Van Halen
A B Buckman Jr
Abby De Lucio von Garro
```

etc.

I'd really like to parse those into logical first name / last name fields.  I used this to strip off the string after the last space:

```
last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(full-name,' ',-1)
```

How can I select everything to the left of the last space?  That would get me 98% of where I need to be and the rest I can clean up in code.  So for example I'd want to select:

```
John A
Mary X Van
A B Buckman
Abby De Lucio von
```

**SOLVED**

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,' ',CHAR_LENGTH(fullname) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(fullname, ' ', '')))
```

Comment: See edit above on how I solved it - thanks to the answers for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the left part of the length of the string after locating the last space

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(full-name, LENGTH(full-name) - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(full-name))+1) 
FROM table;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1403a6/2)

Comment: That's giving me just the first part of the string - I want to get everything to the left of the **last space** - not just everything to the left of the _first_ space.

Comment: @Steve sorry misread that. I just updated with a correct answer

Comment: Thanks - I ended up with something similar and edited the original post.  Accepted yours as answer as well.

Comment: @Steve nice! glad I could help :)